# Hair glitch in cycles

Tags: animation, physics, hair

So I my jumping model has dynamic hair, and with some time hair just start to extend quickly even though I don't have any growth set, it is some kind of a glitch. How can I fix this? I need just normal short dynamic hair that moves slightly. [image: crazy long hair is visible, looks like a glitch]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have modifiers applied to the model? If yes, make sure that the hair modifier is below all other modifiers.